# Smooth a plot and add confidence intervals with R (smooth and geom_ribbon functions on ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, geom-ribbon

I have a numeric variable called 'SP', and an ordinal variable called 'DELAY' with 7 conditions (0.1 ; 0.2 ; ... ; 1.2).
For each of my observations, there are 7 SP values, 1 for each DELAY condition.
Each observation also belongs to a group, 1, 2 or 3 presented in the variable "clusters".
You can see a sample of my data in the code section.

I want to make a plot, that will represent the SP value (y axis) according to each DELAY condition (x axis). It also needs to show separate lines for each group (clusters).

My problems are (ggplot2 package):

- Even if I use the "smooth" function instead of the "line" function, my lines aren't smooth. They just look thicker, not smoother if I may say.
- I want to add confidence intervals but when I use the geom_ribbon my entire plot goes grey.

I think it comes from the way I aggregate my data before I make the plot, but I really had a hard time to just have the right plot in the first place because nothing worked...

Would anyone have a solution to any of these issues ?
I am sorry I don't have enough "reputation" to post images so you need to run the code to actually see the plots.

Thank you in advance for your kind answers !

````
``` r
# LIBRARIES
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("hrbrthemes")

# DATAFRAME
dataSP <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Participant, ~DELAY, ~SP, ~clusters,
  1L, 0.1, 0.788888888888889, 1L,
  1L, 0.2, 0.566666666666667, 1L,
  1L, 0.4, 0.711111111111111, 1L,
  1L, 0.6, 0.8, 1L,
  1L, 0.8, 0.833333333333333, 1L,
  1L, 1, 0.844444444444444, 1L,
  1L, 1.2, 0.866666666666667, 1L,
  2L, 0.1, 0.433333333333333, 1L,
  2L, 0.2, 0.422222222222222, 1L,
  2L, 0.4, 0.488888888888889, 1L,
  2L, 0.6, 0.644444444444444, 1L,
  2L, 0.8, 0.688888888888889, 1L,
  2L, 1, 0.577777777777778, 1L,
  2L, 1.2, 0.611111111111111, 1L,
  3L, 0.1, 0.711111111111111, 1L,
  3L, 0.2, 0.633333333333333, 1L,
  3L, 0.4, 0.611111111111111, 1L,
  3L, 0.6, 0.655555555555556, 1L,
  3L, 0.8, 0.622222222222222, 1L,
  3L, 1, 0.655555555555556, 1L,
  3L, 1.2, 0.644444444444444, 1L,
  4L, 0.1, 0.888888888888889, 3L,
  4L, 0.2, 0.9, 3L,
  4L, 0.4, 0.955555555555556, 3L,
  4L, 0.6, 0.877777777777778, 3L,
  4L, 0.8, 0.855555555555556, 3L,
  4L, 1, 0.922222222222222, 3L,
  4L, 1.2, 0.877777777777778, 3L,
  5L, 0.1, 0.722222222222222, 1L,
  5L, 0.2, 0.577777777777778, 1L,
  5L, 0.4, 0.5, 1L,
  5L, 0.6, 0.588888888888889, 1L,
  5L, 0.8, 0.644444444444444, 1L,
  5L, 1, 0.7, 1L,
  5L, 1.2, 0.711111111111111, 1L,
  6L, 0.1, 0.844444444444444, 3L,
  6L, 0.2, 0.777777777777778, 3L,
  6L, 0.4, 0.744444444444444, 3L,
  6L, 0.6, 0.855555555555556, 3L,
  6L, 0.8, 0.888888888888889, 3L,
  6L, 1, 0.8, 3L,
  6L, 1.2, 0.955555555555556, 3L,
  7L, 0.1, 0.533333333333333, 1L,
  7L, 0.2, 0.688888888888889, 1L,
  7L, 0.4, 0.688888888888889, 1L,
  7L, 0.6, 0.733333333333333, 1L,
  7L, 0.8, 0.844444444444444, 1L,
  7L, 1, 0.8, 1L,
  7L, 1.2, 0.766666666666667, 1L,
  8L, 0.1, 0.455555555555556, 1L,
  8L, 0.2, 0.322222222222222, 1L,
  8L, 0.4, 0.511111111111111, 1L,
  8L, 0.6, 0.788888888888889, 1L,
  8L, 0.8, 0.733333333333333, 1L,
  8L, 1, 0.733333333333333, 1L,
  8L, 1.2, 0.777777777777778, 1L,
  9L, 0.1, 0.388888888888889, 2L,
  9L, 0.2, 0.166666666666667, 2L,
  9L, 0.4, 0.466666666666667, 2L,
  9L, 0.6, 0.477777777777778, 2L,
  9L, 0.8, 0.533333333333333, 2L,
  9L, 1, 0.633333333333333, 2L,
  9L, 1.2, 0.544444444444444, 2L,
  10L, 0.1, 0.477777777777778, 1L,
  10L, 0.2, 0.511111111111111, 1L,
  10L, 0.4, 0.555555555555556, 1L,
  10L, 0.6, 0.633333333333333, 1L,
  10L, 0.8, 0.633333333333333, 1L,
  10L, 1, 0.7, 1L,
  10L, 1.2, 0.6, 1L,
  11L, 0.1, 0.644444444444444, 1L,
  11L, 0.2, 0.544444444444444, 1L,
  11L, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 1L,
  11L, 0.6, 0.7, 1L,
  11L, 0.8, 0.722222222222222, 1L,
  11L, 1, 0.688888888888889, 1L,
  11L, 1.2, 0.7, 1L,
  12L, 0.1, 0.488888888888889, 1L,
  12L, 0.2, 0.477777777777778, 1L,
  12L, 0.4, 0.566666666666667, 1L,
  12L, 0.6, 0.655555555555556, 1L,
  12L, 0.8, 0.611111111111111, 1L,
  12L, 1, 0.633333333333333, 1L,
  12L, 1.2, 0.555555555555556, 1L,
  13L, 0.1, 0.522222222222222, 2L,
  13L, 0.2, 0.311111111111111, 2L,
  13L, 0.4, 0.5, 2L,
  13L, 0.6, 0.577777777777778, 2L,
  13L, 0.8, 0.533333333333333, 2L,
  13L, 1, 0.611111111111111, 2L,
  13L, 1.2, 0.688888888888889, 2L,
  14L, 0.1, 0.544444444444444, 1L,
  14L, 0.2, 0.377777777777778, 1L,
  14L, 0.4, 0.6, 1L,
  14L, 0.6, 0.7, 1L,
  14L, 0.8, 0.722222222222222, 1L,
  14L, 1, 0.688888888888889, 1L,
  14L, 1.2, 0.7, 1L,
  15L, 0.1, 0.822222222222222, 3L,
  15L, 0.2, 0.777777777777778, 3L,
  15L, 0.4, 0.822222222222222, 3L,
  15L, 0.6, 0.7, 3L,
  15L, 0.8, 0.8, 3L,
  15L, 1, 0.855555555555556, 3L,
  15L, 1.2, 0.744444444444444, 3L,
  16L, 0.1, 0.733333333333333, 1L,
  16L, 0.2, 0.588888888888889, 1L,
  16L, 0.4, 0.633333333333333, 1L,
  16L, 0.6, 0.744444444444444, 1L,
  16L, 0.8, 0.777777777777778, 1L,
  16L, 1, 0.744444444444444, 1L,
  16L, 1.2, 0.722222222222222, 1L,
  17L, 0.1, 0.666666666666667, 2L,
  17L, 0.2, 0.277777777777778, 2L,
  17L, 0.4, 0.411111111111111, 2L,
  17L, 0.6, 0.4, 2L,
  17L, 0.8, 0.611111111111111, 2L,
  17L, 1, 0.588888888888889, 2L,
  17L, 1.2, 0.677777777777778, 2L
)


# CODE

# converting group variable "clusters" into characters (to use of a discrete color scale)
clust <- as.character(dataSP$clusters)
dataSP <- cbind(dataSP, clust)

# Generating the plot
ggplot(dataSP) +
  aes(x = DELAY, group = clust, color = clust, y = SP) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "smooth", aes(colour = clust)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  theme_ipsum()


``` r

# TRIED SOLUTIONS

SP.lo <- min(dataSP$SP)
SP.up <- max(dataSP$SP)

ggplot(dataSP) +
  aes(x = DELAY, group = clust, color = clust, y = SP, ymin = SP.lo, ymax = SP.up) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "smooth", aes(colour = clust)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  theme_ipsum()

```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
````

Comment: Hey! Have you tried `geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE)` instead of  `stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "smooth", aes(colour = clust))`? It kind of worked :)

Comment: Hey, thank you @ahmathelte but it draws a straight line, like a correlation plot, it totally erases the characteristic shape of my lines so it's not the right answer for me... Thank you anyway !

Comment: You can change the method or formula in `geom_smooth()` like: `formula = y ~ poly(x, 3)` I hope this will give you the result you want :)

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your answer, yet again, it does not look like my initial curve smoothed, it's better but still weird... Thank you for your time anyway!